# Verify (re-run) client side math calculations on the server

Tags: php, security, math, evaluation

Our users can run mathematical calculations based on form fields. To evaluate the calculation, I'm using **expr-eval** as expression evaluator for javascript (client side) (https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval).

An example expression is: `x = 10; 2 + (4*x)`

For security reasons, we should verify the result of the calculation on server side as well. Therefore, I want to re-run the calculation with the incoming data on the server using PHP, after the form has been submitted.

How would I do that? **expr-eval** comes with a lot of possibilities like ternary conditions, variable declarations and so on. As there is no equivalent library for PHP, what would be the way of running such a verification? I could setup a Node.js server running the **expr-eval**, but would an additional request really be the best practice here?

Comment: https://github.com/AndreiIgna/safe-eval found by googling "php safe eval"

Comment: Instead of running a Node _server_, just write a Node _script_ that you can call with `node verify-math.js base64string` and have that `process.exit(1)` if the math doesn't check out? Then you can make PHP invoke that like any other system call.

Comment: Thanks for this hint @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans! What about security doing it this way? And are there some server requirements to run node scripts from php? The context here is a wordpress plugin – so most users have basic servers.

Comment: If you don't need dynamic variable assignments, you can do this in pure PHP with Symfony's [ExpressionLanguage](https://github.com/symfony/expression-language) component.

Comment: @AlexHowansky already tried that, but unfortunately, variable assignment would be important for our users. So, x = 10 would fail and produce a fatal error in that case :(

Comment: @Vueer "have node installed". You'd just be invoking it using [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), which will return `false` when the command you run returns a non-zero code. (although you can also capture the result code explicitly if you want to assign different non-zero codes for different failure reasons)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans hmm, I think most of the users do not have node installed on their servers..

Comment: You already made them install PHP, tell them to also install Node adds literally "an install" rather than "and then a setup" so should be pretty trivial, just make sure to include instructions on running `npm install` for that JS library you already use client-side.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans True, but the standard WordPress users have shared hosting packages and no influence on them. That's why I can't assume that Node is installed for my solution. So I need another way. :) As context, all those things are running in a WordPress Plugin.

Comment: Can the user specify any arbitrary variable? You say "based on form fields" -- are the variables always taken from the form? I.e., ExpressionLanguage can handle `2+(4*x)` if you pass in `['x' => 10]` as a parameter, so I guess the question is, can you get that `x` and `10` from the form POST, without having to parse that string?

Comment: In that case I'd say "stop verifying things in the browser" and instead verify their math using a PHP math parser that you make JS send their text to, as they type it (by having an endpoint that accepts the input, and a `fetch` call on the JS side as part of your input handler). Or when they click "run", or whatever your UX is for turning typed math into something. That way you can make sure that users only type the kind of math that your _one_ math parser will accept, instead of trying to make PHP understand "something that's valid in JS" on servers that cannot be configured.

Comment: What exactly are you verifying? How do you know if the expression is valid? And what's the consequence of not performing this validation? What would happen if a user disabled JS and submitted an expression that didn't verify?

Comment: If validating in node is not an option the only realistic option to get identical results in both server and client side would be to essentially rewrite the JS code in PHP. The source is [here](https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval/tree/master/src), I'd first try really really hard to exec a node binary (and make the presence of node a pre-requisite).

Comment: @AlexHowansky Just to understand why both, client and server side, is important: the user can use a product price calculator for woocommerce. The calculated price is showing in realtime (ux). After submitting the form, the product will be added to the cart with the calculated price. For security reasons, I need to re-calculate everything on the server, because form data, which is the base for the calculation, could be mutated on client side. Hope that helps to better understand the use case.

Comment: The price should be calculated only on the server.

Comment: @Olivier A configurator application with a good user experience should show you the current price depending on the selection in realtime. Of course I could do that with Ajax, but that would be resource heavy for the server..

Answer (score 0):

Eval will do most of what you need, but:

- it does not handle variables in the way you need
- if you allow *anything* which is not an arithmentic operator or a number to be 'eval'ed then the code is exploitable.

i.e. you're going to need to define your syntax very strictly, implement your own parser then hand off the final expression to eval.

Something like....

```
function safer_eval($expr)
{
  $facts=array();
  $result=false;
  $lines=explode(";", $expr);
  foreach ($lines as $l) {
    $p=explode('=', $l);
    switch (count($p)) {
      case 2:
         $facts[$p[0]]=evalexpr($p[1], $facts);
         break;
      case 1:
         return evalexpr($p[0], $facts);
         break;
      default:
         break 2;
     }
  }
  return false;
}

function evalexpr($expr, $facts) 
{
   $expr=str_replace(array_keys($facts), $facts, $expr);
   if (!preg_match("/^([0-9+-/*\.\(\)\^ )+$/", $expr)) {
      return false;
   }
   return eval($expr);
}
```